# Unknown name \"model\" at 'config': Cannot find field

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use Google Cloud speech (v1beta1) to analyse phone calls. I can't find the "model" parameter in the C# client library, so I'm constructing my own json message and sending it. This works:

```
{
    "audio": {
        "content": "UklGRiavCAA+P8QAAgA....."
    },
    "config": {
        "languageCode": "nl-NL"
    }
}
```

But when I add the phone_call model like this:

```
{
    "audio": {
        "content": "UklGRiavCAA+P8QAAgA....."
    },
    "config": {
        "languageCode": "nl-NL",
        "model": "phone_call"
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"model\" at 'config': Cannot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"model\" at 'config': Cannot find field.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Why? Accoding to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig) I believe my request is valid?

Edit: to answer my own question: turns out I was using a wrong url. The correct url is: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize.

Comment: You should use beta 1 version `v1p1beta1 `

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but it looks like the phone call model  is only supported for en-US, and your language is nl-NL:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics

Scroll down to "Selecting Models". "Command and Search" and "Default" are both listed as available for all languages, but "video" and "phone call" are listed as "en-US only".

Comment: When I change the language to en-US I get the same error message.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not sure what the problem could be, then - I just happened to come across that in the documentation and it seemed like it was probably your issue. Wishing you luck getting someone else to claim the bounty before it closes. It may help a bit to see more code/how you're passing this in, though?

Comment: I was using a wrong url. And as suspected nl-NL is not currently supported.

Comment: Ah, it's always something small! Does that mean you got it working, aside from nl-NL not being supported for the phone call model?